# Swift 4 - How to override tab bar will open view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Is it possible that when a user clicks on a Tab bar item that I can override this in the `UITabBarController` ,  where I then check a `UserDefault` which then decides whether I show the view or `return` and they stay on their current view ?

It would be something like this:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.image == UIImage(named: "TabProfile")
    {
        // Profile tab selected
        if !loginController.isUserLogged()
        {
            // Not logged in...
            showLoginView()  

            // Following line doesn't work...
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
        }
    }
}
```

If possible I want to perform this check and if `false` then actually prevent the view from even reaching `viewDidLoad`.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to avoid adding the tab at all until the user is logged in? Or at least disable the tab bar item until the user logs in?

Comment: @rmaddy I thought about this, but I want the user to be able to navigate all content without having to create an account.

Comment: Your whole question is asking how to conditionally prevent a user from selecting a tab. Maybe I put the wrong condition in my comment but it still stands. Don't add (or just disable) the tab until the condition is met.

Comment: In this case the interaction between the guest user and the profile tab bar item displays the login popup. Which is the desired functionality. Maybe I worded the question wrong and didn't given enough context. Thank you, anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
              shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
   if let ind = tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of:viewController) , ind == 2 { // suppose profile is 2
      // 
       if userNotLogged { 
         // present modal login view 
         return false
       } 
   } 
  return true
}
```